# Add multiple child routes to tab - Ionic Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, routes, ionic4, vue-router

I am currently struggeling with adding multiple Child routes to my tab in an App using Ionic with Vue.js

This works totally fine:

```
{
    path: 'tab3',
    component: () => import('@/views/Tab3.vue')
  },
  {
    path: 'tab3/tab_new_sl',
    name: 'tab_new_sl',
    component: () => import('@/views/Tab_new_SL.vue')
  },
```

But as soon as I add another child route, the app crashes:

```
{
    path: 'tab3',
    component: () => import('@/views/Tab3.vue')
  },
  {
    path: 'tab3/tab_new_sl',
    name: 'tab_new_sl',
    component: () => import('@/views/Tab_new_SL.vue')
  },
  {
    path: 'tab3/tab_show_list',
    name: 'tab_show_list',
    component: () => import('@/views/Tab_Show_list.vue')
  }
```

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call')
undefined
promiseReactionJob
27
```

Maybe one of you can tell me how I define multiple child routes

Answer (score 0):

i think the other paths should be children

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic-vue3-sample-2/blob/master/src/router/index.ts

```
{
    path: 'tab3',
    component: () => import('@/views/Tab3.vue')
    children : [ 
     {
        path: 'tab3/tab_new_sl',
        name: 'tab_new_sl',
        component: () => import('@/views/Tab_new_SL.vue')
     },
     {
        path: 'tab3/tab_show_list',
        name: 'tab_show_list',
        component: () => import('@/views/Tab_Show_list.vue')
     }
    ]
}
```